# JSF Primefaces paginator and rowEdit not working in Unix server(weblogic) while the same EAR working well on windows Developer machien

Tags: jsf, unix, primefaces, weblogic

JSF Primefaces paginator and rowEdit not working in Unix server(weblogic) while the same EAR working well on windows Developer machine. The same code is working on some developer's machine while not on some others. Does anyone have experienced same situation?

Comment: Are JSF libraries the same on the servers? Or are they included in the EAR?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but you could flow this steps 
01.make sure on windows and unix same explorere so Check the explorer version and i prefer to test on same type e.g chrome on the different Os to narrow the problem cause then 
02.check the primefacs version but as you said it's same EAR so ignore it ,
03.check the java build version on your unix for me ,I prefer to use Java from oracle not openJDK 04.check if you need to load any extra liberay on your unix maybe there some lib missing 
good luck